# Is there any specific usage advantage/disadvantage in using createSlice() over createReducer() other than the boilerplate reduction

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I've referred to a couple of links, including https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/81. But it's answered long back in 2019 and not quite helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `createSlice` uses `createReducer` internally, the short answer is no, the main advantage is boilerplate.

Keep in mind though that in `createReducer` and `createSlice`'s `extraReducers` we recommend that you should use the builder notation and not the object map notation as the latter is impossible to simply port over to TypeScript later and advanced stuff like matchers are significantly more easy to use with the builder notation.

Also, I can't think of a single reason to use `createReducer` instead of `createSlice` as long as your resulting reducer has at least one single action type that should be created alongside the reducer.

Comment: Great, That helps!